# Weird hexagons distribution of singular vectors of random matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, svd, random-matrices

I ran the following numerical experiment:

1. Sample 10⁶ random Gaussian 2×2 matrices ($A_{ij}∼(0, 1)$)
2. Compute SVD $A = UΣV^⊤$. Let $u_\max, v_\max$ be the singular vectors of the maximum singular value $σ_\max$.
3. Compute angles $∠(u) = \operatorname{atan2}(u_\max)$, $∠(v) = \operatorname{atan2}(v_\max)$ (see [atan2-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2))
4. Scatter-plot $∠(u)$ against $∠(v)$.

The reason is I wanted to see if there is any structure for this given input distribution, but I certainly didn't expect these hexagonal shapes to appear. Any insights on what might be going on?

**EDIT:** Fixed argument order in `atan2` function and added code.

[image]

```
import numpy as np

MAXITER, M, N = 1_000_000, 2, 2
matrices = np.random.randn(MAXITER, M, N)
us = np.full((MAXITER, M), fill_value=float('nan'))
vs = np.full((MAXITER, N), fill_value=float('nan'))

for k, A in enumerate(matrices):
    U, S, Vh = np.linalg.svd(A)
    u, s, v = U[:, 0], S[0], Vh[0, :]
    us[k] = u
    vs[k] = v

angle_u = np.arctan2(*us.T[::-1])  # takes y as first arg
angle_v = np.arctan2(*vs.T[::-1])  # takes y as first arg

# plotting

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2.5, 2.5), dpi=300, constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot(angle_u, angle_v, ".", ms=2, markeredgecolor="none", alpha=0.2)
ax.set_xlabel("angle u")
ax.set_ylabel("angle v")
ax.set_aspect("equal", adjustable='box')
ax.set_xticks([-np.pi, 0, np.pi], ["-π", "0", "+π"])
ax.set_yticks([-np.pi, 0, np.pi], ["-π", "0", "+π"])
```

Comment: I suspect that the gaps result from a quirk in the algorithm and the non-uniqueness of SVD. For instance, if $A = U\Sigma V^T$ is an SVD, then so is $A = (-U)\Sigma (-V)^T$, which would add $\pi$ to both angles. With that in mind, it might actually make more sense to stipulate that you're looking for an SVD where $u$ has an angle in $[0,\pi)$.

Comment: For reference, here's the plot I get when replicating this experiment in Mathematica: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGquD.png

Comment: To pin things down a bit more precisely, the underlying SVD algorithm is probably a QR algorithm with shifting and deflation, which is an iterative method. I would guess that the initialization is causing this bias

Comment: I was using [`numpy.linalg.svd`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)

Comment: The flexibility between $U,V$ and $-U,-V$ seems to account for the shape entirely. If I add a line of code that negates $U$ and $V$ when $\operatorname{atan2}(u_\max) < 0$, then the new plot I get is just a rectangle. Moreover, the distribution over the rectangle seems to be uniform: [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPKte.png), which buckets the results rounded to the nearest $0.01$ and shows how often each result appears, is just random noise.

Comment: When I try the same thing (also using the numpy svd), I actually end up with the mirror image of what you seem to have gotten

Comment: @BenGrossmann Actually, seems like I overlooked the argument order to atan2 expects `y` in the first component, which gives me this: https://imgur.com/a/3Vvg6Ky

Comment: @Hyperplane I was also making a mistake; I was looking at the second vectors because I somehow forgot that Python arrays are zero-indexed. Looks like I'm getting the same result

Comment: @Hyperplane Interestingly, the behavior of the algorithm is a bit unstable: for matrices that are exactly diagonal with decreasing diagonal entry, the leading singular vectors returned are $[1,0],[1,0]$ as one might expect. For small perturbations of these matrices, the leading singular vectors returned are approximately $[-1,0],[-1,0]$

Comment: @BenGrossmann : In the SVD this is probably hard to find out precisely, but in the end it is the consequence of the fact that there is no unit tangent vector field on the unit sphere.

Comment: @Lutz Interesting, what exactly does the $2$-sphere have to do with the SVD of a $2 \times 2$ matrix? Of course, a circle in 2D space has a unit tangent vector field

Comment: The selection of the bisection vector/reflector normal in the construction of a Householder reflector. These are used in the computation of the bidiagonal matrix at the start of the SVD computation. @BenGrossmann

Answer (score 1):

Not answer, but potentially of interest: I made a histogram/heatmap of the results of a similar experiment for anyone who's interested in the relative frequencies.

[image]

Comment: You can sort of see how, if you took the "peninsulas" on the left (ending at around -0.50 on the $u$ scale) and laid them on top of the "bays" in the middle (ending at around +0.50 on the $u$ scale) then you'd exactly get a uniform distribution.

Comment: @Misha Agreed. The "peninsulas" and "bays" are the same shape, offset horizontally by $\pi$.